# How to make a circle button, and only response the circle area's tap event

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a circle image below:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { alert('tapped') }} style={{width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50}}>
     <Image source={require('./image/more.png')} style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50, overflow: 'hidden', }}></Image>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

It looks right. But when I tap the area between the circle and the rectangle's corner, it still responses the onPress function. How to fix it. Like the iOS's clipsToBounds.

Thank you！

additon:
the preview is below. I tapped on the left bottom, the location is out of the image, but it still act as i tapped on the circle image.
[image]

Comment: Can you try this preview and let me know https://codesandbox.io/s/3rx6jox2rp

Comment: @Aravind S, I have update the question. Thank you.

Comment: try with `hitslop` prop and see

Comment: @Aravind S, thank you. But hitslop can just modify the rectangle area.